# Cloth passing through itself

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]

the cloth object is fall down. then the cloth is collide in the both ends. then they glitch like the picture. they passing through the other end and stuck like that
[image]

Comment: Hello, have you enabled the Self Collisions option? I can't see any link to your file...

Comment: sorry how can i send the blend file

Comment: i have eneble the self collisions

Comment: Read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ or use a platform like workupload and share the link

Comment: ok wait a second

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=RN9z6yOz" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/RN9z6yOz/)

Comment: i already add in the post

Answer (score 1):

Apply the scale of the object, give a negative *Thickness* in the *Solidify* modifier, increase the *Distance* of the *Self Collisions*:

[image]

Comment: ok i will try it

Comment: ya its work, thanks